# How to add all subfolders a folder to PYTHONPATH

Tags: python, path, bashrc

All of my Python module sources are in the folder `/src/*`:

```
/src/module1
/src/module2
    ...
/src/modules100
```

If I want to add all of these modules to my `PYTHONPATH`, I need to add them individually in my `.bashrc` by using the `export` command. Is it possible to add them by one command? (basically adding everything under the `/src/*` folder to my PYTHONPATH)

Answer (score 1):

You can find various options to do that [over on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3430569/435093). One of the easiest:

```
PYTHONPATH="$(printf "%s:" /src/*/)"
```

Here, `/src/*/` expands into all directories under `/src/`. `printf` then uses a colon (`:`) as separator character.